# Installing Android Build using ADB: INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE

Tags: android, google-play, adb

I am trying to install build using adb install command, and i am getting the error:

**INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE**

My scenario is that my app with same package name is already live on Google Play Market and i downloaded the same in my device with version name as 3.2.8 but now when i am trying to install a release signed apk with version name as 4.0.0, i am getting the error.

I am really not getting, how can it be version downgrade.

Please suggest if i can install the new build(4.0.0) without uninstalling the previous one(3.2.8 - market build). 
I don't want to use

```
adb install -r -d
```

Answer (score 0):

It means you're trying to install an app with the same package name as an app that's already installed but the one you are trying to install has a lower `versionCode`.

Also as you can find in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) the `-d` option will not work with the release apk.

```
-d: Allow version code downgrade (debugging packages only).
```

Comment: the one i am trying to install is with the higher version code

Existing version code: 3.2.8
New - 4.0.0

Comment: In your question you are talking about versionName not versionCode. The versionCode is an integer, can't be 3.2.8

Comment: @AnchitMittal The versionCode is a integer. How can you use 3.2.8 that is not an integer?

Answer (score 0):

First, both apk should be signed with same keystore file

Second, If you have install 3.2.8 version from play store & you are going to install 4.0.0 from **adb install -r -d** then it should install & replace.

I have tested it's work. I hope it's clear now!

Comment: i don't want to use -d flag to get app installed. Moreover the QA team is provided with signed apk with same keystore file, and they may not have access to adb for installation. they are also getting error due to this.

Comment: @alpesh In the question is written that he doesn't want to use adb command. Also the -d option works with debugging packages only

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about versionCode which is an integer but you have mentioned your versionName. you have to increment both versionName and versionCode

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 23
versionCode 1    //previous versionCode increment this so new 
                 //versionCOde is 2
multiDexEnabled true
versionName "1.0" //previous versionName increment this so new 
                 //versionName is "1.1"
```

Answer (score -1):

**first uninstall the previous build**

```
adb uninstall your_package_name
```

**then install new build**

```
adb install your_app
```

**OR try this**
You are talking about versionCode which is an integer but you have mentioned your versionName. you have to increment both versionName and versionCode

**For Example**

```
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1    //previous versionCode increment this so new 
                     //versionCOde is 2
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionName "1.0" //previous versionName increment this so new 
                     //versionName is "1.1"
```

Comment: increment both versionName and versionCode